# Ember Router - determine if route/resource is child of current route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

Is there a way I can determine if a given route is the child of the current route?

I'm using the willTransition hook in a Route to determine whether I should display a data-loss confirmation message when the user transitions away from this route.  I don't want this data-loss confirmation to execute if the user transitions between various child resources and routes contained within this resource's router map, but I cannot find a way to determine if the transition I'm given in willTransition is a child of this.routeName.

Any suggestions?

**Router:**

```
Router.map(function() {
   this.route('some-route')
   this.resource('parent-resource', function() {
     this.route('child-route');
     this.resource('child-resource', function() {
       this.route('child-resource-route1');
       this.route('child-resource-route2');
     }
   }
});
```

**ParentResourceRoute:**

```
Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
      willTransition: function(transition) {
        // if transition is not a child of this.routeName display a confirmation alert if there is dirty data 
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I woudn't put that in the willTransition, I'd rather create a method in the parent route that child routes (which are the ones who know what happened) can call to display the alert.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that would work in this case.  I don't want any confirmation to occur when transitioning between the child routes.  The only time I care to determine if there is dirty data is when leaving the parent-resource route and going to one of its siblings.  If I'm doing that check from the child routes, how would I know if I'm about to transition outside the parent-resource?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Ember.Route.extend({
 actions: {
  willTransition: function(transition) {
    if (transition.get('targetName').indexOf(this.get('routeName')) === false) {
      // moving to a sibling or higger route
    }
  }
 }
});
```

May need adjustments according to your route names.

Comment: That works well if I only have a single level of nested child routes - the parent-resource.child-route in my example would be fine.  However, it breaks down once I have nested resources because they would not contain the topmost parent-resource in the targetName.  In this case my leaf routes would be something like child-resource.child-resource-route1.

Comment: `indexOf(anything) === false` will actually never work. Not finding anything will return -1